# Help with unlisted streaming

Tags: youtube, youtube-live

Is it possible to auto-unlist videos AFTER they've been streamed or have I to manually do this myself when the stream has ended?

Or even better, can I set it so people can send me superchats on an unlisted stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Stream Now](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard), you can automatically make your stream unlisted once completed in the stream options.

[image: Stream options > Make archive unlisted when complete]